# How to resolve Android Studio error?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I have used following

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.github.recruit-lifestyle:WaveSwipeRefreshLayout:1.6'
compile 'com.nightonke:boommenu:1.0.9'
```

}

and got the following error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(My Application) from AndroidManifest.xml:18:9-39
>       is also present at [com.nightonke:boommenu:1.0.9] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-41 value=(@string/app_name).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:13:5-48:19 to override.

Android Manifest(application tag)..

> 

```
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

    android:label="My Application"

    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>      </activity>
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the boommenu lib.

Comment: But this worked when I use single library.

Comment: add Application tag of your app at here

Comment: @Sajad Garshasbi I have edited my question.Please check!!

Answer (score 1):

in your manifest file in Application tag add this code:

```
<application
        .
        .
        tools:replace="label">
```

or use an other resource value name for your application name:

```
<application
    .
    .
    android:label="@string/application_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

that application_name is a string value resource in your resource folder

or set value to android:label:

```
<application
    .
    .
    android:label="YourApplicationName">
```